# How to input "#" in git commit window?

Tags: git

How to input "#" in the Git commit window?
It always turns into a comment when I type "#".
What should I do to enter "#" in the git commit window?
Information beginning with the # sign.

Comment: What is a “Git commit window”? Git is a command line tool; it has no windows. Also, what does “turns a commit” mean?

Comment: OP means when you edit the message in an editor or interactive rebase etc.

Comment: @matt: he means "turns into a comment". (s/commit/comment/ and add the preposition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`core.commentChar` configuration](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corecommentChar). https://sadique.io/blog/2013/04/14/configure-gits-comment-character/. It allows you to configure which character is used for comments, so you can set it to something other than # and then use # at the beginning of the commit message.

You can set this option like:

```
git config core.commentChar ";"
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides configuring a different comment character you can use the `--cleanup` option, `git commit --cleanup=verbatim` means do no cleanup at all on the message text.

Git's got a command for answering simple questions like this, `git help`, try it, you'll like it. I found the answer to your question by saying `git help commit` and reading for less time than it took you to type your question.